# Getting and using item id in Shopify js file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify

I am using this code and trying to display some HTML content with append function to a specific class for a specific product that matches their product ID's. Problem is this is not working, maybe I don't know how to collect correctly the product ID that the customer is viewing. Now it either shows on all products or shows on none of the products, depending on the code.

```
$(function () {
if (meta.product.id === '5473068220572'){ 
$(".header").append('<div class="option-values">Testing</div>');
}
});
```

So I want to append that div to header class for 5473068220572 item, how can I do that?

Shopify issue.

Comment: So, what elements have the class `header` ?

Comment: the problem is with (meta.product.id === '5473068220572') part, i do not know what variable should i compare to my specified ID. obviously "meta.product.id" does not work.

Comment: How should we know?  You can use console.log() to verify the value of meta.product.id.  If that's not where the value is stored, we need more info.  What is `meta` ?  Where does it come from?  What is its structure?  Why do you expect the product.id value to be in that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquid variables and objects are not readily available in JavaScript. You have to initialize them in your template files and then use it in JavaScript. In this specific scenario, you can add the following script tag in product template. Add it in product-template.liquid section or some other file that is included while rendering Product page.

```
{% unless product == empty %}
  <script>
    const productInfo = {{ product | json }};
  </script>
{% endunless %}
```

Then in your JavaScript file, check if the variable exist and the ID matches, then append the content.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      if(productInfo && productInfo.id === 123){
        console.log("Id matched");
        $(".product-single__title").append("Added Content");
      } 
    });
```

Above sample code is working fine on Debut Shopify theme.

Comment: This is more close to what I need, though I still struggle as it gives me the error and does not append the wanted things. Here is the error message https://i.ibb.co/jHzYwsD/Screen-Shot-2020-08-13-at-10-46-05-AM.png

and here is the code I currently use:
```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if({{product.id}} === 5473068220572){
    console.log("Id matched");
    $(".header").append('<div class="option-values">Test</div>');
  } 
});
```

Comment: Updated the code. I don't know what theme you are using, where you have included the code. This error is related to jQuery not being loaded. Figure out things step by step rather than focusing on end goal only.

Comment: Seems like the updated version with "document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {" works!!! Thanks